# Eclipse plugin statusbar access

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-plugin

I develop an Eclipse plugin and want to use that status bar to display various messages for the user. Could somebody help how could I access this kind of element? [image: click this for the picture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'status line' is managed through the `IStatusLineManager` interface.

In an editor use:

```java
editor.getEditorSite().getActionBars().getStatusLineManager();
```

to get the manager, where `editor` is your editor part.

In a view use:

```java
view.getViewSite().getActionBars().getStatusLineManager();
```

where `view` is your view part.

The manager has a number of method to show messages and error messages in the status line.